# Barra de progreso en Task Asincrona

Tags: c#, progressbar, programacion-asincrona

tengo un método asíncrono que realiza una consulta a una API de una tienda online, el resultado puede tardar algo y querría poner una barra de progreso mientras dura el proceso, pero no sé ni por donde empezar, alguien me puede guiar por favor?
El método:

```
private async Task<bool> RefreshGridS200(DataGridView dgsWC, Label lblWC)
{
    bool sinResult = false;
    _articlesWC = await CProducte.ObteProductes();
    if (_articlesWC.Count() < 1)
        sinResult = true;
    dgsWC.DataSource = _articlesWC;
    lblWC.Text = _articlesWC.Count().ToString();
    gFiltrats = await EquivalArticles();
    return sinResult;
}
```

A este le paso un `dataGridView` para que me lo llene, me gustaría que se mostrara una barra de progreso mientras lleva a caso la consulta.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pero tus datos van llegando o esperas hasta que llegue todo junto?

Comment: No, la idea es esperar a tenerlo y mostrarlo todo.

Comment: Deberia colocar alguno que gire y no una barra de progreso, porque sino lo deberias hacer pasar rapido apenas llegue la info. si Pones un spinner gira hasta que lo ocultes.